# Ensuring a table is an object of a class?

Tags: oop, lua

I've made a class `Apple`

```
Apple.lua

function apple_new()

    local self = { }

    local size = 1

    function self.grow()
        size = size + 1
    end

    function self.size()
        return size
    end

    return self
end
```

I want to define a `function(table)` which returns `true` if the parameter `table` was originally created by the function `apple_new`. I have not currently found a way to ensure 'fake apples' cannot return `true` in that function.

```
AppleTest.lua

function is_apple(table)
    if type(table) ~= "table" then return false end

    return table.grow ~= nil and table.size ~= nil
end

local x = apple_new()
local y = { size = function() end, grow = function() end }
is_apple(x) -- true
is_apple(y) -- true, but it's a fake apple
```

I believe a solution exists with metatables, utilizing the `__metatable` metamethod. However I'd prefer a solution without them if possible. This is rather difficult because any variable inside of a table can be copied.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Apple.lua`, add this

```
local Apples = { }
setmetatable(Apples, {__mode = "k"})

function apple_new()
    local self = { }
    Apples[self] = true
    ...
    return self
end

function is_apple(table)
    return Apples[table] == true
end
```

To allows apples to be garbage collected, you need to make `Apples` a weak table.

Comment: I had no idea weak tables were possible. Thanks!

Comment: @lhf - OP's functions `is_apple` and `apple_new` are defined in different files.

Comment: and if so: `local y = { size = function() end, grow = function() end  }  Apples[y] = true`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement inheritance and class functions, you can also do it the way it is done in [Programming In Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html).

```
Apple = {}
Apples = {}

function Apple:new (initTable)
    local a = initTable or {}
    table.insert (Apples, a)

    setmetatable (a, self)
    self.__index = self

    return a
end
```

Now any functions you define for Apple will be available to any object you create using the Apple:new function.  All Apple when created will be automatically part of the Apples table.

Comment: I'm using the [closure approach](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationClosureApproach) in that article. It seems to looker nicer and perform faster while only losing a bit on memory. Also it circumvents the `:` syntax. I'm not too happy using the metatable as proof of class because the `getmetatable` method can cause havoc if the user has access to it. You can hide the metatable through `__metabletable` but then that prevents extending the class later on.

Comment: If you use the setmetatable method, you can compare constructor functions on the instance of your object against the class object:

    local a = Apple:new ({foo = 'bar;})
    local isAnApple = (a.new = Apple.new) -- true